# How to Create a CVOpenGLTextureRef from a OpenGL Texture

Tags: cocoa, opengl, core-video

I have a little Project setup using OpenGL and Core Video. I render to a FBO and use this as a Texture for other parts of the Programm, but it would be nicer to pass this Texture reference in form of a CVOpenGLTextureRef . But i cant find any Useful doumentation how to create this datatype from a Texture Name and Target (without copying any data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, to *read* data from an OpenGL context, you need to use a `CVOpenGLBufferRef` (which is a type of `CVImageBufferRef`). The documentation claims that these wrap pbuffers, but I would guess they work with FBOs. I haven’t tried it.

To *render* the data from a `CVOpenGLBufferRef`, you need to draw it to a texture using a `CVOpenGLTextureCacheRef`, which manages a set of `CVOpenGLTextureRef`s.

If you only want do draw the unmodified buffer contents, it’s probably more efficient to work within OpenGL. (Note that you can share textures/buffers between contexts using share groups, if necessary.)

If you do need to shuffle buffers around between contexts, and don’t want all that fluffy high-level abstraction and helpful documentation that you get with Core Video, you might want to look into IOSurface and CGLIOSurface.

Comment: Well yes, thats the point i am actually stuck. How do I tell a CVOpenGlBufferRef or a CVImageBuffer to reference a OpenGl texture, indicated by a (GlUint) Texture Name? CIImage for example has such a method. Greetings

Comment: So why didn’t you ask that, then? `CVOpenGLBufferAttach()` will cause anything you render into the specified OpenGL context to be drawn to your `CVOpenGLBufferRef`.